# Binding temporary to a lvalue reference

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, lvalue, rvalue

I have the following code

```
string three()
{
    return "three";
}

void mutate(string& ref)
{
}

int main()
{
    mutate(three()); 
    return 0;
}
```

You can see I am passing *three()* to *mutate* method. This code compiles well. My understanding is, temporaries can't be assigned to non-const references. If yes, how this program is compiling?

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

Compilers tried : VS 2008 and VS2010 Beta

Comment: Try GCC it is more near to C++ standard.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have GCC with me.

Comment: @Appu: After I fixed your code for missing includes and `std` prefixes, Comeau (http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) says: `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`. The reason that VC accepts this is because VC is broken. (They call it a "feature", but actually it's a bug.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It used to compile in VC6 compiler, so I guess to maintain backward comptibility VS2008 is supporting this non-standard extension. Try with [/Za](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d(VS.100).aspx) (disable language extension) flag, you should get an error then.

Comment: Specifying `/Za` option could lead to problems with including `windows.h` or other windows specific headers.

Comment: Using Warning level as four is better option that is what I used

Answer (score 4):

It is VC++'s evil extension. If you compile with /W4 then the compiler will warn you. I guess you are reading the [Rvalue References: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx). This article also mentioned that issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Microsoft Extension, to mimic the behavoir of many other microsoft compilers. If you enable W4 warnings, you will see the warning.

Answer (score 1):

It *doesn't* compile, with g++ 4 at least:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:16: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string&’ from a temporary of type ‘std::string’
foo.cpp:10: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void mutate(std::string&)’
```

(The line numbers are off by 3 or 4, because I had to add the #include and 'using' lines.)

So, your compiler appears to not be as strict as it should be.

Comment: Edited post and added compilers I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the compiler. g++ 4.1.2 gives me this.

```
In function 'int main()':
Line 15: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&' from a temporary of type 'std::string'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Maybe because you're not doing anything the call is optimized away.

Comment: I tried to do something with the ref parameter inside mutate() method and it still compiles

Comment: I tried it in VC++ just now and it compiles and works unless you disable extensions in the project properties. When you do you get this:

1>main.cpp
1>d:\all\projects\laptop\2\asd\asd\main.cpp(16) : error C2664: 'mutate' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string &'
1>        A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue