# Is it a bug that Microsoft VS C++ compiler can Initialize a reference from a temporary object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, temporary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binding temporary to a lvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345382/binding-temporary-to-a-lvalue-reference)

With VS2008 C++ compiler, the codes are compiled without compile error.

```
class A{};

int main(){
    A& a_ref = A(); 
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the C++ standard, both C++2003 and coming C++0x, disallow it. And I also get a compile time error with gcc compiler.

So what I want to know is, is this a known bug for VS compiler to allow initializing reference from a temporary object.

Or is it a feature extension of VS compiler? If yes, what's life cycle of the temporary object?

Answer (score 1):

It is the extension.This link explains it.  [What if we take out the const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)