# why the reference of temporary object is valid here?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a bug that Microsoft VS C++ compiler can Initialize a reference from a temporary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501014/is-it-a-bug-that-microsoft-vs-c-compiler-can-initialize-a-reference-from-a-tem)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class test
{
public:
    string a;
public:
    test(string b){a=b;}
    friend string operator+(test);
};
string operator+(string &c,test a)
{
    c=c+a.a;
    return c;
}
void main()
{
    test d("the ");
    test e("world!");
    string s="Hello ";
     s=s+d+e;
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

the second last line **s=s+d+e;** after the fist overloaded operator + it returned a  temporary object,and the second overloaded operator + unexpectedly worked!But the first parameter of operator+ function is a reference. why the reference of temporary object is valid here,or there is something i have missed?

P.S: It's compiled by VC++6.0 and here is the running result.[image]

Comment: It's an "extension" supported by MS compilers since before the language was standardized. VS2010 warns about this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any temporary objects. Where is the temporary object?

Comment: @MrLister: Look closer - the `operator+` used here returns by value - so it is indeed a temporary.

Comment: But it is a real string, a real object. The problem with temporary object references exist only if you create an object in a function and then return a reference to it, because the object gets its destructor called when the function ends. That is not the case here! You return the value of c!

Comment: @MrLister: The value returned by `operator+` is a temporary object, valid until the end of the full expression. You're correct that it's not a reference to an automatic object destroyed when the function returns; but that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary objects last until the end of the full-expression in which they are created - roughly speaking, until the `;` at the end of the line. References to them are valid until that point.

However, it's not valid to bind it to a non-`const` reference as you do. The only reason that compiles is because your compiler is over 15 years old, and the language has been through two major changes since then. I suggest you upgrade to one of this millenium's compilers.

Comment: But you'd still require a `const` reference for this to be well-defined, or am I wrong there?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Good point, I didn't spot that. I assumed it must be valid since the OP said that it compiles; but reading more carefully, it's only been compiled in a prehistoric, non-standard compiler.

Comment: And it doesn't compile nowadays: `c = c+ a.a` is ambiguous.