# Filtering specific iterators for template functions

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am developing a set of functions that takes advantage of containers that have packed and sequential memory storage (for memory copies).  They have function signatures in the style of most STD functions, input/output iterators point to elements and denote ranges.  For instance, a function could look like this:

```
template< typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator >
OutputIterator fooBar( InputIterator& first, InputIterator& last, 
                       OutputIterator& result );
```

I wish to verify that the iterators passed are legal, that is packed and sequential.  For the STD containers, this is limited to std::vector and std::array.  Unfortunately, I can't rely on the iterator 'category' trait, because the random access trait does not imply seqential storage.  An example of this is microsofts concurrent_vector class, documented here [parallel containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In addition, I can't accept all iterators from the vector and array classes either, for instance i need to reject reverse iterators, and std::vector`<bool`> iterators are unsuitable because of the proxy class that it uses.

I've attempted to create my own traits class to distinguish and filter the iterators with the constraints that i describe above, but i'm running into template syntax problems.  I am looking for feedback from others on how they would approach this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You also need to watch out for the `value_type`. Only PODs can be `memcpy`'d. Usually, most std libraries already try to optimize `std::copy` to a `memmove` when possible, why don't you just use it?

Comment: The nature of this library is such that POD's are given.  It comes with the domain.  I can go into details if anybody is interested, but I tried to state my question as generically as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this. Iterators are an abstraction whose whole purpose is to make the iteration process independent of the underlying architecture. There is no information in the standard iterators that denote the underlying memory structure or even anything remotely similar.

On your std-algorithm-like functions, it's generally advised to pass iterators by value, since they should be cheap / small objects. It should be especially noted that your function would never be able to be called as `fooBar(c.begin(), c.end(), some_out_it);`, since it takes the the input iterators by reference-to-non-const.

As a last point, you can filter out reverse iterators by testing whether the iterator type is a specialization of `std::reverse_iterator<Iter>`, since atleast the `Container::(const_)reverse_iterator` type of standard containers are required to be one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The approach that I am researching involves creating a 'new' traits class, so I want to add my own information to an iterator.  Very similar to how the iterator_traits class works now, i just have to make sure the iterator_traits is well defined for the iterators i care about [SGI iterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iterator_traits.html)  Also, this allows users to create their own iterators and add their own trait metadata.  Can you show me documentation about iterator-pass-by-value?  I'm not familiar with that.  Also, Why do the input iterators have to be const?

Comment: @Kent: I think you need to have a good read on how argument passing in C++ works. `void foo1(int);`, for example, takes an `int` by value. `void foo2(int&);` takes an `int` by reference, and the reference is non-`const`. Now, Let's say you have a function `int bar();`, which returns an int by value (which is a temporary value). You cannot call `foo2(bar())`, because temporaries cannot be bound to a reference-to-non-const. Hope that helps understanding the matter a bit better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Turns out that Microsoft compilers accept reference-to-non-const [microsoft binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345382/binding-temporary-to-a-lvalue-reference), but it is not standard compliant behavior.

Comment: @Kent: Correct, MSVC is too lenient in this regard.