# Binding a reference to a temporary objects

Tags: c++, opencv, rvalue, temporary-objects

To my understanding, a reference cannot be bound to an expression returns a temporary object(aka rvalue). So what follows should be illegitimate:

```
auto& a = cv::Vec3f::all(0.f)
```

where the definition of static method `cv::Vec3f::all()` is

```
template<typename _Tp, int cn> inline
Vec<_Tp, cn> Vec<_Tp, cn>::all(_Tp alpha)
{
    Vec v;
    for( int i = 0; i < cn; i++ ) v.val[i] = alpha;
    return v;
}

typedef Vec<float,3> Vec3f;
```

While above code was compiled successfully in Visual Studio 2013, the type of `a` is identified as `Vec<float,3>&`. Who can help me out?

Comment: I would be very suspicious of VS2013 here. Have you tried this on other compilers?

Comment: It is VC++'s [evil extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1345382/3309790).

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a _feature_" - Microsoft

Comment: Apple Clang, GCC, Regular Clang and MinGW reject this code.

Comment: Per songyuanyao, possible duplicate of [Binding temporary to a lvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345382/binding-temporary-to-a-lvalue-reference)